# Timeout exception when timeout set to infinite time

Tags: nhibernate, timeout, castle-activerecord, sqlexception, command-timeout

In my C# .NET 3.5 application I am using CastleProject ActiveRecord over NHibernate. This is desktop application using MS SQL Server 2008. I have set ADO command timeout to 0 to prevent timeout exception during bulk operations:

```
  <activerecord>
    <config>
      ...
      <add key="hibernate.command_timeout" value="0" />
    </config>
  </activerecord>

  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      ...
      <property name="command_timeout">0</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

However, I am still receiving timeout exception! The NHibernate log shows something like this:

Somewhere at the beginning:

> 2010-10-02 06:29:47,746 INFO 
>   NHibernate.Driver.DriverBase - setting ADO.NET command timeout to 0 seconds

Somewhere at the end:

> 2010-10-02 07:36:03,020 DEBUG
>   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher -
>   Closed IDbCommand, open IDbCommand s:
>   0 2010-10-02 07:36:03,382 ERROR
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener
>   - Could not syn chronize database state with session
>   NHibernate.HibernateException: An
>   exception occurred when executing
>   batch queries ---> System.Data.S
>   qlClient.SqlException: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to completion of the opera tion
>   or the server is not responding.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)

How come? How to fix this?

Comment: this a web application I'm assuming?

Comment: Sorry, did not state this. No, this is regular desktop application.

Comment: Are you using batching (`adonet.batch_size` > 0) ? Why do you have an ActiveRecord configuration *and* a separate NHibernate configuration? What kind of SQL statement is timing out (update/insert/select/delete)? What version of NHibernate and ActiveRecord are you using?

Comment: @Mauricio: Yes, I am using batch_size=1000. I have two configurations because in the past I met situations when one key works being defined in ActiveRecord section while another works only for Nhibernate so I decided to have both (maybe this is wrong). The statement is insert, batch insert. Nhibernate is 2.1.2.4000 and CastleProject is 2.1.0.6692.

Comment: I have a theory... try setting batch_size to 0, and see if it still times out. Please post back here with the result.

Comment: @Mauricio, you are right, it does not fail with batch_size equal to 0. What is the theory?

Comment: BTW normally you should not have two configurations... unless you know what you're doing ;-) If you're using ActiveRecord just use an ActiveRecord configuration.

Comment: The proper timeout config key is `command_timeout`, not `hibernate.command_timeout` (which IIRC was renamed in NH 2.0)

Comment: Will try with "command_timeout". Strange that ActiveRecord did not fail like it does when meet unknown configuration options.

Comment: I deleted all timeouts/batch-sizes from ActiveRecord section. However, it won't run in case I remove hibernate.dialect and hibernate.connection.provider, so I left them. All other options, including command_timeout and adonet.batch_size I left only in hibernate-configuration. I am still receiving exception about disconnected transaction (which is described in the new issue I opened).

Comment: @Alex: the "hibernate." prefix was removed in NH 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct that a value of 0 indicates no timeout (as [defined in the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)), however while [NHibernate's driver passes the config value to the db command when it's >= 0](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Driver/DriverBase.cs?revision=5225&view=markup#l139), the batcher's condition [checks that the value is > 0](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/AdoNet/SqlClientBatchingBatcher.cs?revision=5112&view=markup#l98).

Therefore, when you set batching on, with a timeout value of 0, the value isn't carried over to the db command so it remains as default.

It's entirely possible that this is by design, and that NHibernate developers intentionally disabled disabling timeouts for batch scenarios. Disabling timeout is a bad idea anyway, if you have troubles with timeout errors I would raise the value, but not disable it.

Please confirm this with NHibernate devs.

Comment: I tried to increase timeout time (from 1000 to 10000) and decreased batch size (from 1000 to 100), now I get exception NHibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not connected, or was disconnected on quite random place of my batch operations. Why?

Comment: Hm... I get timeout exception once more what is impossible for such long timeout value. One of my friends said me that Nhibernate TransactionScope I am using do not use custom timeout. Do you know any workaround to populate timeout from config file to TransactionScope?

Comment: @Alex: please post another question.

Comment: Posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855315/timeout-exception-when-using-nhibernate-transactionscope

Comment: How to set batcher connection timeout through fluent nhibernate?

Comment: @Johnny_D : please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking to set the timeout for specific queries and not at web.config level (otherwise you really need to tune up your application :) ).

I've recently found this answer that helped me:

[How to set Nhibernate LINQ Command Timeout using Session.Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890395/how-to-set-nhibernate-linq-command-timeout-using-session-query)