# How to set Nhibernate LINQ Command Timeout using Session.Query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, timeout, command-timeout

Is anyone aware of a way to set the `UnderlyingCriteria` when using `Session.Query`?

I'm trying to set a more restrictive command timeout (or query timeout) for one specific query and I am trying to avoid adding that constraint on the connection or other querys in the session.

I've found in the old `QueryOver` functionality you could use something like this

```
// QueryOver returns a IQueryOver<T,T> an nHibernate class 
// with access to UnderlyingCriteria

var query = Session.QueryOver<Puppy>();
query.UnderlyingCriteria.SetTimeout(120);
```

The problem with that is it's old, buggy, and just has a slew of functional issues.

Using `Query` returns an `IQueryable<T>`

```
 var query = (from c in Session.Query<Puppy>());
```

`IQueryable` is a MS class with no apparent access to command timeouts etc.

Another option would be to somehow set the sessions command timeout for all commands, at that point, then revert to the default, but I'm not seeing any public mechanism for doing this, beside setting the command timeout up front and leaving it so, like [How to set timeout for NHibernate LINQ statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919361/how-to-set-timeout-for-nhibernate-linq-statement)

Answer (score 6):

Never mind, found an example in Nhibernate's unit tests, they've added some extension methods to IQueryable.

```
var query = (from c in Session.Query<Puppy>()).Timeout(12);
```

Comment: I find setting it globablly more helpful
<property name="command_timeout">240</property>

Comment: That's useful when you want to set the default for an entire application, but the goal behind the question was to change it for an individual command's timeout :)

Comment: For recent code users (2024 is my current year) the equiv would be `var query = (from c in Session.Query<Puppy>()).WithOptions(opt => opt.SetTimeout(12));`